# ipinfodb.com API

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml, ip

Hello again stackoverflow!

So i build this script:

```
<?php
$xmlurl = 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query.php?key=apikey&ip=127.0.0.100&timezone=false';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl);

if($xml->status == 'OK'){
    echo '<br>'. $xml->CountryName;
    echo '<br>'. $xml->RegionName;
    echo '<br>'. $xml->City;
}
else
{
    echo $xml->status;
}
?>
```

This is returning a white page?
No errors, no warnings...

But while i do print_r it does show an array?

Comment: What result do you get if you paste that URL directly into your browser?  Do you know 127.0.0.100 is a "reserved" IP address?

Comment: No i edited it for the example...

Comment: Do you provide an api key? I tried to call the same API, but got a result which contained the expected elements (I guess) with no data within and this message "<Status>INVALID API KEY</Status>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the elements and thus the properties of the result of your `simplexml_load_file` call are *case-sensitive*. Therefore you should change the negative branch code to:

```
echo $xml->Status;
```

(notice the capital S).

The same applies to your if condition:

```
if($xml->Status == 'OK'){
```

Comment: For anyone trying to do this with api v3, you also have to specify &format=xml on the end of the URL.